# How to get tweeter data from past years using R?

Tags: python, r, twitter, functional-programming, web-scraping

I would like to get tweets regarding certain string from past 4 years. I am using the following code

```
searchTwitter('dieoff', n=9000, from = '2010-01-01', until = '2015-05-30')
```

Using this, I was able to get 43 tweets.

But when I tried the same code with different duration (only 1 year and half)

```
searchTwitter('dieoff', n=9000, from = '2014-01-01', until = '2015-05-30')
```

I also got 43 tweets. How can I solve such a problem. I would like to get tweets from past 4 years. I am willing to try this out in any language.

Comment: You can't search tweets more than a week old with Twitter's search API -- see [this thread](https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-limit-on-search-api-to-limit-tweets-less-than-a-week-please-help-is-there-any-way-to-search-tweets-with-a-hashtag-that-is-older-than-2-weeks/7710) for more discussion.

Comment: @KaraWoo You should probably make this an answer, the link you posted makes it clear what the OP wants isn't possible with the Twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible using the `searchTwitter()` function because Twitter's search API limits results to within the last week or so (per [this thread](https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-limit-on-search-api-to-limit-tweets-less-than-a-week-please-help-is-there-any-way-to-search-tweets-with-a-hashtag-that-is-older-than-2-weeks/7710)). I have heard of some workarounds, maybe using `rvest`, but haven't tried any of these myself.

Comment: I understand your suggestion. If the API is not able to retrive history from twitter then it might be better to get data from topsy.com. The data is there but Is it possible to just download that data or even scrape their site for data using R?